# Numeric and Conditional Formatting with rhandsontable

Tags: javascript, r, formatting, rhandsontable

I'm finding that I can either numerically format the rhandsontable or conditionally format the style of the rhandsontable, but not both. Using the following code, it seems that only the javascript portion of the code is being used. I'd greatly appreciate any help to incorporate both formatting types.

```
DF = data.frame(int = 1:10, float = rnorm(10), cur = rnorm(10) * 1E5,
                lrg = rnorm(10) * 1E8, pct = rnorm(10))

rhandsontable(DF, width = 550, height = 300) %>%
  hot_cols(renderer = "
           function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
             Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
            if (row == 2){
              td.style.background = 'lightyellow';
           }}") %>%
  hot_col("float", format = "0.0") %>%
  hot_col("cur", format = "$0,0.00") %>%
  hot_col("lrg", format = "0a") %>%
  hot_col("pct", format = "0%")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference NumericRenderer rather than TextRenderer

```
DF = data.frame(int = 1:10, float = rnorm(10), cur = rnorm(10) * 1E5,
            lrg = rnorm(10) * 1E8, pct = rnorm(10))

rhandsontable(DF, width = 550, height = 300) %>%
  hot_cols(renderer = "
       function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
         Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
        if (row == 2){
          td.style.background = 'lightyellow';
       }}") %>%
  hot_col("float", format = "0.0") %>%
  hot_col("cur", format = "$0,0.00") %>%
  hot_col("lrg", format = "0a") %>%
  hot_col("pct", format = "0%")
```

Issue is discussed here https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/issues/45